# Erro ao ler variável usando WeakMap

Tags: javascript

```js
var person = {
    nome: 'Bruno',
    sobrenome: 'Coelho'
};
nomeMap = new WeakMap();
function nomeCompleto(){
    nomeMap.set(this, {
        nome: person.nome
    });
    nomeMap.set(this, {
        sobrenome: person.sobrenome
    });
    return console.log(nomeMap.get(this).nome + ' ' + nomeMap.get(this).sobrenome);
}
nomeCompleto();
```

Eu não entendi porque ele só faz a leitura do sobrenome e não a variável nome, como posso resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A última instância está anulando a primeira. Use apenas uma, desta forma:

```js
var person = {
    nome: 'Bruno',
    sobrenome: 'Coelho'
};
nomeMap = new WeakMap();
function nomeCompleto(){
    nomeMap.set(this, {
        nome: person.nome,
        sobrenome: person.sobrenome
    });
    return console.log(nomeMap.get(this).nome + ' ' + nomeMap.get(this).sobrenome);
}
nomeCompleto();
```